# How to merge specific branch, denying others

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-merge, git-config

How to configure git to allow the merge of the PROD branch to be allowed by the branch HOMOL and HOTFIX and denied by branch DEV
[image]

Comment: [This](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159872/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-merging-origin-x-into-y-in-git) is similar to your query.

Comment: Your wish isn't best practice. You should set branch `PROD` in **protected branch** mode.

Comment: Is this really a Github question?

Comment: @ThiruShetty, yes this is basically this, but there is no solution there.

Comment: yes, it gives you some hints